# Listbox object transfer in C#

Tags: c#, listbox

having a frustrating problem with listboxes with C#.

I have a class "worker", wich has parameters "id number", "name" and "pay". The objective is that I have two listboxes, lets call them 1 and 2. 1 has some worker-objects in it, so that it only displays the name of the worker. I have a button that's supposed to copy the selected worker to box2, so that box2 displays also the id number and pay, with the name. So far, I have only managed to make it so that it copies the name and nothing else.
Thanks a lot for all tips!! :)
(sorry my english, as I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Read this before post questions.

Comment: Is this WPF? WinForms? Can you show the code?

Comment: ListBox doesn't care what your object looks like, it just calls its ToString() method to produce the text on the screen.  Surely your 2nd listbox shows the same text since it uses the same ToString() method.  Use another class or use the DrawItem event or separate the view from the data and just use strings.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set the `DisplayMember` of the receiving `ListBox` to the name of the property in your class you want to be displayed instead of the `ToString()` result.

This assumes that you have public properties in your class..
If you show us your class `worker` we'll see if it will work.

It also assumes that you don't just copy the name but the whole `ListBox.Item`!
If you show us your code we'll see if it will do..